# how do I put variable in an angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

Hello (kind of a greenhorn question),

i have the following:

```
 $scope.updateInline = function(fctr, item, fieldName){

        var obj = {};
        obj[fieldName] = item[fieldName];
        obj['id'] = item.id;

        [fctr]update( {id:item.id}, obj, function (data) {

            if (!data.error) {
                notify({ messageTemplate: $scope.notifyMsg.UpS, classes: 'alert-success', duration: 3000});
            } else {
                notify({ messageTemplate: $scope.notifyMsg.UpE, classes: 'alert-danger', duration: 3000});
            }

        });

    };
```

in my html:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.clientId" ng-ng-change="updateInline('Invites_Fctr',item, 'clientId')" />
```

how do I pass the Invites_fctr from the html to the [fctr] on the .update function

the [fctr]update(....) is not working.  my syntax is not good.

I hope this is clear.
thank you

Comment: Please rewrite your question to make it clearer and add all the relevant code.

Comment: edited the question, I hope this is clearer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly you want to do this, but you might try saving the factory as a scope property:

```
var factories = {"Invites_Fctr": InvitesFactory, "List_Fctr": ListFactory}; //Assuming they are properly injected onto the controller.
$scope.updateInline = function (factoryName, item, fieldName) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[fieldName] = item[fieldName];
    obj['id'] = item.id;
    factories[factoryName].update({id: item.id}, obj, function (data) {
        if (!data.error) {
            notify({messageTemplate: $scope.notifyMsg.UpS, classes: 'alert-success', duration: 3000});
        } else {
            notify({messageTemplate: $scope.notifyMsg.UpE, classes: 'alert-danger', duration: 3000});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: my goal is to make a DRY update function.  I want to pass from the html, the factory_name, the item and the fieldName.  This way one update function can work for all situations.

Comment: check if the approach i've provided works for your purposes.